# Use ggtitle and facet wrap in a loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I did a sentiment analysis on a considerable amount of .txt files, the results of which are in a list of data-frames (listtxt). Each data-frame in that list represents the analysis for one .txt file.

So listtxt for the 7th and 8th txt file look like this

```
[[7]]
     element_id word_count        sd ave_sentiment
  1:          1          1        NA    0.00000000
  2:          2          8        NA    0.00000000
  3:          3         15        NA    0.25819889
  4:          4         28        NA    0.28347335
  5:          5         45 0.1689353    0.05695529
 ---                                              
115:        115        104 0.1864339   -0.33659356
116:        116         60 0.5830784   -0.11404312
117:        117         83 0.1694059    0.20015495
118:        118         54 0.3094642    0.18327970
119:        119         30 0.4849154    0.36961306

[[8]]
     element_id word_count        sd ave_sentiment
  1:          1          1        NA   0.000000000
  2:          2          7        NA   0.188982237
  3:          3         15        NA   0.258198890
  4:          4         98 0.2573836   0.018342501
  5:          5         85 0.3151697   0.009575169
 ---                                              
167:        167         60 0.1950696   0.182300225
168:        168         65 0.2226071   0.338903560
169:        169         12        NA   0.230940108
170:        170          8        NA   0.353553391
171:        171          3 0.0000000   0.000000000
```

I made a separate dataframe dfsummary, of which the variables (name, date, ...) provide an overview of each txt file analysed.

which looks like this

```
dfsummary.
       V1       Year   Name      V2
    1 "Poem"    1000   Person1   a   
    2 "Poem"    1001   Person1   b
    3 "Poem"    1002   Person1   a
    4 "Poem"    1003   Person2   b
    5 "Poem"    1004   Person2   b
    6 "Poem"    1004   Person2   b
    7 "Poem"    1005   Person2   a
    8 "Poem"    1006   Person3   a
```

I'm trying to make a loop so that each dataframe in listtxt can be plotted based on the row in dfsummary it is linked with. Then facet_wrap the plots with each name they're linked with.

here's my code.

```
  for (i in dfsummary) {
  title <- paste("poem", dfsummary$Name[i], dfsummary$Year[i])
}
```

then for the plots

```
for (i in (listtxt)){
    sentiment.plots <- pblapply(listtxt, function(x)
      p <- ggplot(x, aes(x, y)) + 
        geom_jitter(...) + 
        geom_smooth(...) +
        ...
        ggtitle(paste0(title)))

  }
```

The code returns the plots in a list, but with "NA" values in the title for both dfsummary$Name[i], dfsummary$Year[i]

Does anyone have any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Allocate space for storage before 1st loop: title <- vector(“list”). Then add title[i] <- in loop to create list of plot names. Then use ggtitle(title[i])? If you provide a reproducible example we can help more.

Comment: You overwrite `title` each iteration through the loop, so when your title loop ends, you only have the value of the last title still around. In fact, no loop is needed for the titles because `paste` is vectorized. And you'd then use `title[i]` in the second loop. *That said*, your loop is set up to work if `dfoverview` is vector of row numbers... of the same length as `listtxt`, but it seems like a weird way to set things up, and I'm not sure how `pblapply` fits in. Your second loop has a similar overwriting problem... my guess is there are more problems here and you should share some data.

Comment: If the issue really is just the titles, use `titles <- paste("aaa", df$Name[dfoverview], df$Year[dfoverview], "bbbb")` instead of the first loop, and `titles[i]` in the second loop. If that doesn't work, please post some sample data in a copy/pasteable way (like with `dput()`) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, I have added additional data to make it more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Without any data I cannot produce your exact scenario. But here is a reprex that does what you describe: Use 1 loop to create list of title names and another loop to create plot of lists using the names from the title list. The comments above describe some of the issues and this is just a small example showing one way to fix using the data set iris.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Name = c("one", "two", "three"),
                 Year = c(2018, 2019, 2020))
#if explicitly want a loop
title <- vector() #allocate space for storage 
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
 #use [[i]] to avoid overwriting title object each time
  title[[i]] <- paste("aaa", df$Name[i], df$Year[i], "bbbb")
}

#but as Gregor points out much easier to do this:
title <- paste("aaa", df$Name, df$Year, "bbbb")

plots <- vector("list")
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  plots[[i]] <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length))+
    geom_point()+
    ggtitle(title[[i]]) ##specify with [[i]] what title to use
}

plots[[1]]
```

"plots[ [ 1] ]" will display:
[image]

Comment: Why use a loop and a `list` for the titles? `title <- paste("aaa", df$Name, df$Year, "bbbb")` give a nice `character` vector of titles. You only need lists when things don't fit in vectors, and you only need loops when functions aren't vectorized.

Comment: You are right. Wasn't sure if OP explicitly wanted a loop. But will update showing this (which is much simpler).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, it's much appreciated. I have shared additional data to make it more comprehenisble

Comment: Hey @bs93, I modified your code, if you don't mind, because I need a plot for the dataframes inside my list. I modified your code, using lapply to get the df's inside the list. I don't have NA va

Comment: hey @bs93, thank you for your help! I modified your code using lapply, if you don't mind because, I need to plot the df's inside listtxt. I have no NA values now but the years on all the plots is, the year at the end of the loop, that is, the final year in dfsummary

Comment: Once your run this line: title <- paste("aaa", dfsummary$Name, dfsummary$Year, "bbbb"). Does the character vector output of this 'title' object give the correct titles for the plot?